# Are SSL certificate chains different among desktop and tablet browsers?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got a Nexus 7 tablet with Android 4.4.2 and browsers Chrome and FireFox installed on it. When I open the website https://ib.sb24.com with it, it prompts me that the certificate is not trusted but when I open the same address with a desktop browser it's alright! Why is that?

**[UPDATE]**

By desktop I mean Windows and Ubuntu, Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: That site is using a cert issued by Turktrust, which has had some trouble in the past that I think resulted in it being excluded or removed from some systems; also it uses a "chain" (intermediate) cert which is not in the server handshake as it should be (tested with openssl s_client). My Win7 store has both root and chain so Chrome and IE there are happy, but my Firefox/Win has that root (and some others) but not chain and is unhappy, and my Vista has neither. I don't know who provides the truststore on Android, and if or how you can add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the server is configured wrong. It only sends a single certificate which is not signed by a known root, but instead by an intermediate CA. But the server forgets to add the needed intermediate certificates too.
The reason it works in your browser that you once browsed a site where the same intermediate CA was used and the browser cached the CA. Probably all browsers do that to help with such misconfigurations, but this does not help if the browser never visited a properly configured site with the right intermediate CA before visiting the misconfigured site.

If you don't believe me try to visit the same site with a fresh firefox profile, you will get the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome most likely uses platform native store/list of trusted root certificate authorities therefore root CA which is trusted on your desktop platform (i.e. Windows) may not be trusted on Android platform.

Comment: @Mehran SSL certificate used at that site was issued by TÜRKTRUST CA  which was removed from several root CA lists after [their last security incident](https://www.google.com/search?q=TÜRKTRUST+incident).